# Timer with merge stop emitting value even though the parent source stream still emit new ones

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6, reactivex

I try to merge 3 stream status of my app to 1. The cycle is disconnect <-> connect <-> authed. So whenever the app only connected to the server, it will try to send auth every 3 second. Unless it is disconnected or already authenticated.

I am using rxjs timer to send auth on to-be-merged stream and takeUntil to stop sending the auth if the it has been authenticated. But the problem is instead of completing the sendAuth stream, merged auth$ stops emitting new response even though to-be-merged auth$ still emitting response. Here's the code:

```
this._response$ = fromEvent<string>(this._socket, "response")
  .pipe(map(data => JSON.parse(data)));

const disconnect$ = fromEvent(this._socket, "disconnect");
const connect$ = fromEvent(this._socket, "connect");
const auth$ = this._response$.pipe(
  // this stream still emitting even if takeUntil is declared on connect$.
  filter(res => res.action === "authentication" && res.type === "success"),
);

status$ = merge(
  disconnect$.pipe(
    map(() => {
      this._status = statusEnum.OFF;
      return this._status;
    })
  ),
  connect$.pipe(
    // will send auth each 3s after connected
    // until it is authenticated or disconnected
    switchMap(() => timer(0, 3000).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('Sending auth right after connect')),
      map(() => this._sendAuth()),
      // completing the status$ stream instead of switchMap
      takeUntil(auth$),
    )),
    map(() => {
      this._status = statusEnum.ON;
      return this._status;
    }),
  ),
  auth$.pipe(
    // this stream stop emitting if takeUntil is declared on connect$.
    map(() => {
      this._status = statusEnum.AUTHENTICATED;
      return this._status;
    })
  ),
);
```

**EDIT**:
Merged auth$ start emitting value again after adding share operator to to-be-merged auth pipeline.

```
const auth$ = this._response$.pipe(
  // this stream still emitting even if takeUntil is declared on connect$.
  filter(res => res.action === "authentication" && res.type === "success"),
  share(),
);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what happens. Completing one merged Observable doesn't complete the whole stream.

Comment: @martin yes, after I check again the status$ doesn't trigger complete function on subscription. Sorry, I am new to this, should I create a new question or just edit this question?

Answer (score 1):

```
// assume a isConnect stream which return a boolean indicate connection status
let isConnect$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

// assume a behavior subject to store a auth status
let isAuth$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

disconnect$.subscribe(() => this.isConnect$.next(false));

connect$.subscribe(() => this.isConnect$.next(true));

// combine isConnect and isAuth together
let status$ = combineLatest(isConnect$, isAuth$).pipe(
  map(() => (isAuth ? statusEnum.AUTHENTICATED : isConnect ? statusEnum.ON : statusEnum.OFF)),
);

// a timer for sending auth every 3 secs and only send if status is statusEnum.ON;
let auth$ = timer(0, 3000)
  .pipe(
    switchMapTo(status$),
    filter(status => status === statusEnum.ON),
  )
  .subscribe(() => this.sendAuth());

// in this.sendAuth, after successfully get auth, you have to make isAuth$.next(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you are implying that the timer couldn't be completed with takeUntil?

Comment: you can make it completed if your status$ not going to switch between on and off